# Fancybox "leaving this site" popup

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I'm trying to create a fancybox popup for a childrens mobile site.

- It will only appear for external links
- It presents links to continue to the external website link or to close the fancybox and return to the page

The only solution I've been able to find so far is using something like this for each link...

```
<a id="external" href="#external-block">Go to external link</a> 

<div style="display:none">
<div id="external-block">
<h2>Warning</h2>
<p>Hey, you're leaving this site <p>
<a href="onclick="$.fancybox.close();">Return</a>
<a href="http://actuallink">Leave the site</a>
</div>
```

and in the js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("a#external").fancybox();
});
```

But it's redundant for each link. I'd like to find a way to have one js function that detects if a link on the page is external, and when it's clicked instead of going to the url it grabs the href and makes (i.e. not having a hidden div for each link) a fancybox popup with messaging to go to that url or go back.

Comment: "no luck" - what do you mean here? It does the job, but not in the way you intended? Literally nothing happens? Something in between?

Comment: Meaning I've gotten fancybox to work, that's not the problem. But, the only solution I've been able to make work is having a `(a.link-id).flexbox` declaration for each link i'd like to be external which calls a hidden div from the page into flexbox, and that div has the link in it.

Comment: So, please include your partial solution in your question and explain your issues with it (code is always good, and you should be able to edit your question).

Comment: If you only want to select anchor tags that are linking externally, you could use `a[href^="http://"]` which would select all anchor tags where the href attribute starts with `http://`. This would work so long as you don't use `http://` for any of your internal links.

Comment: Thanks, that definitely helps @beardy it's only part of the problem though.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I've edited the question to hopefully make a bit more sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is using fancybox a requirement? This could probably be simpler without it.

You could create a single hidden fixed element which would act as the light-box and make the box visible whenever a link is clicked on. Granted you would also need to add your own functionality to hide the box by having a close button, but that should be simple enough.

To set the external link inside this new light-box you would simply do something like this:

```
$('a[href^="http://"], a[href^="https://"]').click(function(e) {
    // This is used to override the default event and
    // stop the browser from redirecting the user to the url.
    e.preventDefault();

    // Set the href for the #external_link element inside the lightbox
    // to the one from the anchor tag that was clicked on.
    $("#lightbox #external_link").attr("href", $(this).attr("href"));

    // Show the light-box
    $("#lightbox").show();
});
```

If you're after the fading effects that fancybox offers, I'd recommend taking a little time to read up on [CSS transitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Using_CSS_transitions).

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I was looking for. :) I was using fancybox just for the modal dialog, now that a couple of lines of jquery can get it to show, it's CSS transitions to the rescue.

Answer (score 1):

You could set an event handler on all `a` elements, check if it's an external link and then open a fancybox window. Something like:

```
$("a").on("click", function(e) {       
    if ($(this).attr("href").indexOf("http://")>-1
       ||
       $(this).attr("href").indexOf("https://")>-1)
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        message = "<div>This site opens in a new window<br/>" + 
                  "<input type=\"button\" value=\"Continue\" " +  
                     "onclick=\"location.href='"+$(this).attr("href")+"';\">"+
                  "</div>";
        $.fancybox(message);

    }
});
```

​
The "Continue" button in the fiddle won't work because it blocks external links, but it's working code:
http://jsfiddle.net/6nfWJ/

Comment: I wish I had enough reputation to +1 your solution. Works as expected. Thanks mate!